# How to user/pass a class inside a UserControl in C#?

Tags: c#, controls

I have a folder A that contains a class FirstPageControl. This class derives from another PageControl.
I have another folder B that contains a User Control called PageUserEditor. 
I want this control to contain a FirstPageControl. 
The PageUserEditor will be the control that contains any logic that would be used regardless of where in the application it gets put. 
How do I use or call the FirstPageControl in the PageUserEditor? Do I need to add in PageUserEditor all imports that are in FirstPageControl?

(The code base is in C#)

Comment: And where is your code ?

Comment: You haven't even mentioned whether you use ASP.NET, Winforms or WPF

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm using Winforms, and I'm pretty much new to C# and Winforms both

Comment: You need to publish the interface from the nested UC. This could be a couple of public properties or fields or methods or all of it..  Keeping these references small & few is part of the art of object design..